# Regex/Xpath find pages with a specific string within div container (Screaming Frog SEO)

Tags: regex, xpath

With Screaming Frog SEO is possible using XPath or Regex to extract certain elements from a source .

Now I'd like each page showing the " test10 " word , But the word is on all pages in the submenu. So the word needs to be in a specific part of the source . I have tried many many many times , but it just don't work out the way it should be.

Example

```
<div id="contentContainer">
... (several other div's and content ...
test10 ... (several other div's and content ...
</div>
```

I only wants to know which page contain the word 'test10' with the contentContainer.

Can anybody help me out here, please?

With regards,
Jelte

Answer (score 0):

We can use `contains()` to check if any element inside the desired `div` has `test10` in the text:

```
//div[@id="contentContainer"]//*[contains(., "test10")]
```